# Transform flat object into array of single property objects

Tags: ecmascript-6

What is the most succinct way in `ES6+` to transform this:

```js
{
  'key 1': 'value 1',
  'key 2': 'value 2',
  'key 3': 'value 3'
}
```

into this:

```js
[
  { 'key 1': 'value 1' },
  { 'key 2': 'value 2' },
  { 'key 3': 'value 3' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), then [Array.Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), along with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to transform the single object into an array of key / value pairs:

```js
const obj = {
  'key 1': 'value 1',
  'key 2': 'value 2',
  'key 3': 'value 3'
}

const arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
console.log('Result:', arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another way to approach this is simply to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript), then accessing each value using obj[key]:

```js
const obj = {
  'key 1': 'value 1',
  'key 2': 'value 2',
  'key 3': 'value 3'
}

const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }));
console.log('Result:', arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```